# Catch push notification by app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to catch each push notification by app?

I've found, that app can catch notifications if app launched, or if user taped by one message.

App use

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler
```

for this.

But if device got two or more notifications all of them will be lost after tapped on one of them (app catch only one). Or if user suddenly remove push notification.

So is it way to save every notification (bounded with my app of course)?

Comment: If the user had removed registration for push notification your app won't be able to fetch them. You could think about work arounds, depends on your app's use and create a custom notification banner that you could trigger by code.

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate class there a method `application didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. You can use that to track all notifications received by the application

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {

//Track your notifications.
//Save your notifications.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

APNS architecture, by design, only stores the most recent push notification. 
This is because delivering the push notifications to the client is not reliable, the device might be offline, user might have declined receiving push notifications, network ports blocked or several other reasons.

This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as *'coalescing notifications'*.
More information here:
[APNS Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

On the client side, the behavior is the same, and once you launch the app, you will only have in your dictionary only the payload from your last received notification. The payloads don't stack up.